# Save ImageView in a activity staticly

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, onsaveinstancestate

In my code I have 2 activitys, first one is "telaInicial" (a navigationdrawer working as as menu), when I click on "criarAnalise" it goes to another one named "Analise", at the Analise activity I have 4 blank images, when the user press a certain button, the image1, or 2 or 3 or 4 changes it to another one.

I also have a button that uses "finish()" so the user can go back to the first activity. I wanted to do something to save the images even after closing the activity "Analise",so if the user go to this activty again, the Images he chose will be there, and not blank.

**Analise Activity:**

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.reator1) {
        fotoequipamento=R.drawable.reatorcomaquecimento;
        Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Equipamento adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      enviarImg1();

    } else if (id == R.id.reator2) {
       fotoequipamento=R.drawable.reatorfluidizado;
        Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Equipamento adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enviarImg1();
    } else if (id == R.id.tanque1) {
        fotoequipamento=R.drawable.tanquecilindrico;
        Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Equipamento adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enviarImg1();
    } else if (id == R.id.tanque2) {
        fotoequipamento=R.drawable.tanqueesferico;
        Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Equipamento adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enviarImg1();
    } else if (id == R.id.caminhao) {
        fotoequipamento=R.drawable.caminhaotransp;
        Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Equipamento adicionado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enviarImg1();
    } else if (id == R.id.voltar) {
       finish();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
 public void enviarImg1{


    //HERE THE USER WILL CHOOSE WHAT PICTURE HE WANTS TO PLACE WHERE
    if ((int) equipamento1.getTag() == R.drawable.branco) {
        equipamento1.setImageResource(fotoequipamento);
        equipamento1.setTag(fotoequipamento);
        botaoapagar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

        else if ((int) equipamento2.getTag() == R.drawable.branco) {
        equipamento2.setImageResource(fotoequipamento);
        setapreta1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        equipamento2.setTag(fotoequipamento);
        botaoapagar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

    else if ((int) equipamento3.getTag() == R.drawable.branco) {
        equipamento3.setImageResource(fotoequipamento);
        setapreta2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        equipamento3.setTag(fotoequipamento);
        botaoapagar3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
    else if ((int) equipamento4.getTag() == R.drawable.branco) {
        equipamento4.setImageResource(fotoequipamento);
        setapreta3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        equipamento4.setTag(fotoequipamento);
        botaoapagar4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);} else {Toast.makeText(Analise.this,"Espaço indisponível no diagrama.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} }

    }
```

I tried using saveinstance, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all selected image by user either in global variable like mainActivity or application class variable or use well know `sharedpreference` to store data to use later even after restarting  app after some time or some days. you can recover selected images from `sharedpreference`.

On the other hand global variable like `mainActivity` or application class variable will store data until application close. When the app is closed, or killed by another application or the OS, you will lose the data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you explain to me how I use global variable?